# Adobe Brackets 0.41 - CSS auto-completion error while in Live Preview

Tags: css, adobe-brackets, live-preview

When:

- Live Preview is running
- I'm writing CSS
- & I hit Enter to use an auto-completion recommendation

Then:

- The auto-completion occurs
- The cursor skips down a line & indents

I usually work around this annoying cursor movement by closing Live Preview, but I'd really rather not. Is this a bug or am I missing something? How can I fix it to where it just simply fills in the auto-completion recommendation?

Thanks!

*Brackets 0.41
Windows 7*

Answer (score 0):

Brackets doesn't normally behave this way - you may have an extension installed that's causing trouble. Try using *Debug > Reload Without Extensions* and see if the problem still happens. If that fixes it, you can systematically [disable individual extensions](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Troubleshooting#disable-all-extensions) until you find which one was causing the problem. I believe the "Emmet" extension has caused some similar issues in the past, so that might be a good one to check first.

Once you know which extension causes the problem, I can walk you though filing a bug with the extension's author so it can be fixed.

If you're seeing the issue even after *Debug > Reload Without Extensions*, then it would be good to get more specific with the steps that trigger the problem. For example:

1. Open the default "Getting Started" project and open its main.css file
2. Start Live Preview
3. Add a new line to the end of the `body` rule
4. Type `font-w` and press Enter
5. type `b` and press Enter

When I do these steps, no extra newline is inserted. What steps should I use instead to see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found this as I was experiencing the exact same issue. Try disabling any scripts called in your html one by one to see if it goes away. My issue was a script I was loading from a Wu